# Keras how to write parallel model, for multiclass prediction

Tags: python, keras

I have the following model, where keep_features=900 or so,y is one-hot encoding of classes. I am looking for the architecture below though(is that possible with keras, and what would the notation idea look like,specially the parallel part and the concatination)

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(keep_features, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss=losses.categorical_crossentropy,optimizer='adam',metrics=['mae', 'acc'])
```

[image]

Comment: Have you considered that softmax with only one neuron would always produce a constant 1.0 output?

Comment: I see that issue, i guess an additional question is how would i get these dense softmax 1 layers to output a confidence value for the respectiv class?

Comment: Check out chapter "Multi-input and multi-output models" [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/). It explains how to do a multi-input multi-output model in Keras with examples

Comment: thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the chapter "Multi-input and multi-output models" [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) you can make something like this for your desired model:

```
K = tf.keras
input1 = K.layers.Input(keep_features_shape)

denseA1 = K.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(input1)
denseB1 = K.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(input1)
denseC1 = K.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(input1)

batchA1 = K.layers.BatchNormalization()(denseA1)
batchB1 = K.layers.BatchNormalization()(denseB1)
batchC1 = K.layers.BatchNormalization()(denseC1)

denseA2 = K.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(batchA1)
denseB2 = K.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(batchB1)
denseC2 = K.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(batchC1)

batchA2 = K.layers.BatchNormalization()(denseA2)
batchB2 = K.layers.BatchNormalization()(denseB2)
batchC2 = K.layers.BatchNormalization()(denseC2)

denseA3 = K.layers.Dense(32, activation='softmax')(batchA2) # individual layer
denseB3 = K.layers.Dense(16, activation='softmax')(batchB2) # individual layer
denseC3 = K.layers.Dense(8, activation='softmax')(batchC2) # individual layer

concat1 = K.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([denseA3, denseB3, denseC3])

model = K.Model(inputs=[input1], outputs=[concat1])

model.compile(loss = K.losses.categorical_crossentropy, optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae', 'acc'])
```

This results in:
[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks, great. Just note for anyone stumbling on this last layer should be sigmoid or sth to produce sth sensible